# Replaced anchor tag text when click on edit but at a time replace for one item?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am working on table field so when I click on first  'Edit' it will replace with 'Save' text and vice versa but what I need is, 
When  'edit' text   replace as 'save' so it is mandatory to click on 'save'  text then only next edit able to replace their text to 'save' else not change text

```js
$("body").on('click','.clk',function(){            
            var edit_id=$(this).attr("data-id");            
            if($(this).text()==='Edit'){
                $(this).text('Save');
            }
            else{
                $(this).text('Edit');
            }            
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <a class="clk" data-id="1" >Edit</a>    
    <a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit</a>    
    <a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit </a>    
    <a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit</a>
```

Comment: Please try to rewrite it so I can understand. Use full stops and sentences.

Comment: If I click first button, first button should be "save" others should be "edit" like this you need right

Comment: When click on edit it will replace as save text but if I  click on every edit every edit  without click on save text next edits should not replace with save text

Comment: @parvez check the below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this `$(this).text('Save').siblings().text('Edit');` in your jquery it will be works...

```js
$("body").on('click','.clk',function(){

        var edit_id=$(this).attr("data-id");
     $(this).text('Save').siblings().text('Edit');
        /*if($(this).text()==='Edit'){
            $(this).text('Save');
        }
        else{
            $(this).text('Edit');
        }*/

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="clk" data-id="1" >Edit</a>

<a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit</a>

<a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit </a>

<a class="clk" data-id="2" >Edit</a>
```